# Unknown "268" DIP-14 IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, dip

I have been going through a container of old electronics and discovered a set of ten DIP-14 ICs labelled "268."  I have searched this number as well as the additional unique number on each chip, but have had no luck identifying them.

[image: 268 IC Photograph]

Does anyone in this community recognize this chip?
Might someone have a data-sheet on hand?

Thank you

Comment: That looks like it's a customer specific or non-standard part number, but the manufacturer is Signetics from the logo.

Comment: Logo could also be [System General](http://www.sg.com.tw/Index_I_E.asp)? I just looked through [this list of logos](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_identify_integrated_circuit_(chip)_manufacturers_by_their_logos/all_logos).

Comment: The logo is Signetics' and the number next to it is the date code encoded as the last two digits of the year followed by the week of that year.

Comment: According to Wikipedia's list of 7400 series ICs, "74268 - 6 hex d-type latches three-state outputs, common output control, common enable". EDIT: scratch that, [74S268](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/150/501211_DS.pdf) have 16 pins

Comment: Holy Cow! Those are proprietary chips from 45 years ago! Lots of luck figuring those out. If you can find a source of early Signetics catalogs, you might try looking through them.

Comment: Thank you all very much.  Many of the chips I am sorting are old, in fact I have hundreds of unsorted ICs in cans, and a few in metal DIPs.  Identifying them is quite a chore!

Comment: sgs T74LS268B1 obsolete 14 pin dip... 55c in runout in the 1980's. ...

Comment: @david Do you have any sources for me to follow to figure out more?  My end-goal is to have at least a pin-diagram.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a TTL version of [74F286 9 bit parity checker (1987)](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-067/DSA2IH00214936.pdf), but no guarantee: they might have just used the same number.

I suggested T74LS268B1 because it is a little-known SGS 74 series 268 about which I have no further information, but even that only because that I think that would be a pin-compatible part: with that '69-'70 date code, it won't be LS technology.